# R - Importing a CSV file and Transforming it to column-based format

Tags: r, import, transformation

I am currently working on a script that performs statistical analysis on a certain type of data which involves treatment, subject, date, body mass, and a few other, mostly nonrelevant measures.

As of now, I had a nice format structured around reading data in a simple way, where each index is a unique measurement taken, whereas each column is the variable measured. Thus, each index was a unique combination of all listed variables that appeared as column headers. **The 1st image shows this**.

[This is the old format data that I would like to align the new format with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q42Jd.png)

However, I am now dealing with a new type of csv file with a bunch of complications. This csv file has made unique indexes of subject and treatment, and has nested columns for each date. Each of the larger date columns contains several nested columns, involving specifically body mass (BW), food intake (FI), Blood glucose (BG), and Hopper. **The 2nd image shows this**. For now, I am only interested in body mass out of these four variables, so I don't mind if they need to be deleted for simplicity or ease of function.

I need to be able to transform this format into my old format, whereupon date, tag, subject, treatment, and body mass are all their own columns, and each unique measurement is a row. Currently, as you can see in the image, this is not the case.

[This is the new format data, with only 2 dates. The sets of columns keep going in my actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BYV9.png)

As of now, I have tried only pivot_longer to open up the dataframe and achieve the goal of spreading out all measurements into unique rows/indexes.
However, this has not really worked for a few reasons.
Firstly, the nested columns seem to be causing importation of the csv file to cause R to assign new "X" tags to all column headers. I am assuming this is since I have technically multiple rows, but the first row only has one value, the date, for more than one nested columns.

I manually tried to use the column names R was providing me to run pivot_longer, but it returned the data in an extremely odd format, where most of the data was hidden, and clicking on certain columns after using View(df) caused certain data to show. After a lot of examining it, I have not fully understood exactly what R is doing with the simple importation.

I would essentially like a function to accomplish the goal of retaining each measurement's match to treatment, subject, tag, and date, while turning the dataframe into a long set of columns with unique measures, as shown in image 1. It would also help to have a function that carries out importation neatly and in accommodating for the unique structure of the second dataset. Anything except the actual body mass (BW) measurement can be repeated. I am unsure if unnesting is required or not.

I would truly appreciate any guidance on this, and please let me know if the question would benefit from additional information. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: Hardly anyone will bother reading a question this long, and text-only. Please make a concise question with a single issue. Multiple issues or operations usually require multiple questions. NEVER include links to screenshots of the data, but rather include data as code we can copy to work on in our machines

Comment: Please share the code you tried and the unexpected output. Sample code is always better than a textual description of the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO. This all may look like harsh criticism, but you will benefit greatly from going through some guidelines and SO basics. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I offer a slight softening of this: please don't link ***only*** images of data. An image is fine, but please give us something we can use without having to resort to attempting OCR or ChatGPT-interpretation of an image of data. Your question is a bit long, and without something more actionably, there's not much we can do. Also, an image of a spreadsheet can be usable, but in this case if you want R to read the contents of a CSV file, it is far more helpful to include the literal raw text (at least the top `n` lines) of the CSV file in a [code block] in the question. Something we can _use_.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. As you can see, this is my first post and I appreciate your guidance. I will update my question, and hopefully offer a more clear picture of my problem then. Thank you for taking the time for offering this advice!